# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'response.profileObj' as it is undefined at (Login.jsx:14:1)

Tags: reactjs, react-google-login

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
  const responseGoogle = (response) => {
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.profileObj));
    const { name, googleId, imageUrl } = response.profileObj;
    const doc = {
      _id: googleId,
      _type: 'user',
      userName: name,
      image: imageUrl,
    };
    client.createIfNotExists(doc).then(() => {
      navigate('/', { replace: true });
    });
  };
```

im still new to coding and was following javascript mastery tutotial but ran into this error.

Answer (score 0):

Because It is the old version of google-login. You should go [react-oauth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-oauth/google)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).